# If humans move to different solar systems will they eventually evolve into different species?

Tags: interstellar-travel, exoplanet

I once read an argument against space settlement in a newspaper that said that if humans move to different systems eventually they will evolve into different species, or their cultures and beliefs will diverge so much that the later generations may identify themselves as too different starting wars that may wipe out humanity. The authors main argument for this was that the communication between such settlements will be so slow that it will eventually die out.....is this plausible?

Comment: If even communication would be so slow there wouldn’t be room for wars imho.

Comment: Ha didnt see that coming

Comment: I wouldn't see biological or cultural divergence as an argument against space settlement. It's just something that would happen, eventually. Even if the biological part takes a hundred thousand years... And when you consider historically, for instance, one Germanic tribe warring with another Germanic tribe (or Celtic, or whatever), it's not like people have to be culturally or biologically different from each other to go to war with each other.

Comment: People start wars for the tiniest of differences, or for no reason at all. However, in the case of different species one often ends up *eating* the other!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the concept of species evolution is outside the purview of this site (Space Exploration) except for perhaps the short-term evolution of microorganisms in space stations (experimental or otherwise) There could be a good biology question here somewhere but it would require some added prior research.

Comment: The title and body don't match.  The title asks about _species_, which means that members of different groups would be unable to reproduce together.  The body asks about _culture_, etc., which is no different than what has already happened here on Earth.  These are two fundamentally different questions, at least one of which doesn't belong in this site.

Comment: To evolve into a different species would take hundreds of thousands of years. Maybe millions of years.